# How to clear OUT parameters of a CallableStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

I was wondering if there was a way of clearing OUT parameters of a CallableStatement, in the same way that there is a clearParameters() method for bound parameters of a PreparedStatement. As CallableStatement extends PreparedStatement, I tried with the clearParameters() method, but it does not reset OUT parameters.

Example:

```
CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall("call myStoredProcedure (?)");
statement.registerOutParameter("myOutParameterName", Types.VARCHAR);
statement.clearParameters();
statement.execute(); //still working despite clearParameters()
System.out.println(statement.getString("myOutParameterName")); //still working despite clearParameters()
```

Comment: Can I ask you why do you want to clear the OUT parameter ? generally people create a statement and execute the query and close the resultset, statement and connection. can you please explain ?

Comment: I am implementing a JDBC library to perform easy cache lookup, which is very annoying to do when using prepared queries. I store the bound parameters to generate a key to perform cache lookup, and reinitialize the store parameters when calling clearParameters(). I also store IN or OUT parameters of CallableStatements, and want to be sure there are no ways to reset the OUT parameters. I am very surprised it is not doable. Why allowing it for bound parameters, but not for OUT parameters...